# Array type safety function arguments accessed with compound literal

Tags: c, compound-literals

There is a method which is defined in this manner:

```
void corruption(int (*idata[1]), bool (*flags[3]), bool* (*finfo[2]), int* (*error[1]));
```

I am trying to pass information to it using compound literals while also respecting type-safety definition, but I have a problem with this.

```
Argument  (*idata[1])  is information which is being checked.
Argument  (*flags[3]) are information which suggest the method what to do
Argument *(*finfo[2]) are information which are updated by the algorithm changing the original value
Argument *(*error[1]) are information which are updated by the algorithm changing the original value
```

I do not know how to pass anything to this function via compound literals without producing errors or unwanted behaviour. The reason why I want to try and do this with a compound literal is because I am trying to avoid assigning the information to separate variables since there are variables which already exist in code. I've tried writing this, but of course it does not work.

```
int data = 5151;
bool f1_flag = false;
bool f2_flag = false;
bool f3_flag = true;
bool* f1_info = points to some variable;
bool* f2_info = points to some variable;
int error_code = 0;

corruption
(
    &(int(*)){ &(int[]){data} },
    &(bool(*)){ &(bool[]){f1_flag, f2_flag, f3_flag} }, 
    &(bool []){ &(bool(*)){ &(bool[]){f1_info, f2_info } } },
    &(int []) { &(int[]){error} }
);
```

Compiler warnings which I receive for argument 1 and 2 are:

```
/* warning: initialization of 'int *' from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)[1] */
/* warning: initialization of '_Bool *' from incompatible pointer type '_Bool (*)[3] */
```

Of course argument 3 and 4 produce warning as well and cause segmentation fault.

Comment: what is it ? `int (*idata[1])`

Comment: Can you show the body of `corruption`?  I suspect the parameter declarations are not really what you want.

Comment: What arent' the `idata` and `error` parameters simply `int *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not understand the types well.

```
void corruption(int *idata[1], bool *flags[3], bool **finfo[2], int **error[1]);

void foo(void)
{

    int data = 5151;
    bool f1_flag = false;
    bool f2_flag = false;
    bool f3_flag = true;
    bool *f1_info = &f1_flag;
    bool *f2_info = &f2_flag;
    int error_code = 0;

    corruption
    (
         (int *[]){&data},
         (bool *[]){&f1_flag, &f2_flag, &f3_flag}, 
         (bool **[]){&f1_info, &f2_info},
         (int **[]){&(int *){&error_code}}
    );
}
```

Comment: For OP's sake, the compound literal for `error` could also be written as: `(int **[]){(int *[]){&error_code}}`.

Comment: @IanAbbott no you need the address of it. The first one creates pointer to int, the second one needs pointer to this pointer and defines a single array of pointers to pointers

Comment: It is not the same as I have since I do not want int(*) to decay to int*, but thanks to your solution I managed to find a solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @0___________ They are effectively the same, thanks to the array decaying to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @IanAbbott more logical to use int compound litelar and reference to it. Using array is the same but will be confusing for OP.